# java how to send email via any account

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am able to send email using this code below. But I need to change the mail.smtp.host and mail.smtp.port depending on which type of account the user has.

I am creating an App where I want the user just to supply his email address and password, and then the code figures out the details. Is there a way to do this? I could try try and figure the type of account from the email address but it is not always obvious.

```
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.BufferedWriter;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.FileWriter;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
    import java.nio.charset.Charset;
    import java.nio.file.Files;
    import java.nio.file.Paths;
    import java.util.Properties;
    import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.activation.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

public class MailProjectClass {
    //final static String username = "info@mail.com";
    //final static String password = "xxxx";
    final static String username = "yyyy@gmail.com";
    final static String password = "yyyy";
    static Transport bus;

public static void main(String[] args) {



    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", true);
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", true);

    //props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtpout.europe.secureserver.net");
    //props.put("mail.smtp.port", "80"); //25, 3535, 80    465    
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587"); //25, 3535, 80    465

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                }
            });


        sendEmail(session,"zzzz@wherever.com");


  }

    public static void sendEmail(Session session, String emailAddress)  {

        try {

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,  InternetAddress.parse(emailAddress));
            message.setSubject("Homework");

            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("alternative");

            MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();


            String content = "Blank";
            try {

                content = readFile("C:\\Letter.txt", Charset.defaultCharset());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            messageBodyPart.setContent(content, "text/plain"); 
            messageBodyPart.setDisposition(Part.INLINE);
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            try {

                content = readFile("C:\\Letter.htm", Charset.defaultCharset());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            messageBodyPart.setContent(content, "text/html"); 
            messageBodyPart.setDisposition(Part.INLINE);
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);


            message.setContent(multipart);

            Transport.send(message);


        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
```

EDIT 1

If I do want to code most of the details needed myself - is there a **java class** that does the dialogue for me - i.e. allows for getting all the different information needed depending on the account type?

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that, otherwise there would be million of sites offering you to access your Email wherever it is, Username and password alone are not enough to determine which SMTP you need unless you cover the known ones by parsing the Email adress which is not what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could do as follows,

1. Create a static map with 'gmail' as key and 'smtp.gmail.com' as value like this put all the mail details such as gmail, hotmail, yahoo and etc..
2. Create one more static map for port with 'gmail' as key and '587' as value.
3. Before adding host & port into properties, Get the Host & port from map based on your username. Get the key from username substring.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever attempted to set up an email client such as Outlook Express, Thunderbird, or various others? If so, you'll know that they need far more information that just an email address and password. This might serve as a clue that what you want can't be done.

Answer (score 0):

Things you can try to figure out server settings:

- Store the data for big providers (hotmail, gmail, etc.) in your program, that should cover the majority of the cases
- check the mx record for the host part of the email on your nameserver, this will give you the SMTP server for that domain, in most cases the IMAP/POP3 Server is the same.
- Try the default ports on these servers and try to connect with the possible protocol combinations (SMTP/POP3/IMAP with SSL/TLS/plain/etc...)

But there will always be settings the user has to choose, for example if he wants to use IMAP or POP3.